# username/password for jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk-kvm.img?

Tags: authentication, disk-image

what is the username/password combo for https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/jammy/current/jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk-kvm.img ?
i have tried `root:blank` and `ubuntu:blank` and `ubuntu:ubuntu` , wasn't any of those. and fwiw i'm starting the image like this:

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 \
-machine accel=kvm \
-cpu host \
-smp cores=4 \
-m size=1G \
-serial stdio \
-boot menu=on,splash=/root/boot.bmp,splash-time=1000 \
-drive media=disk,file=jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk-kvm.img,if=virtio,cache=unsafe,format=qcow2,werror=report
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't have a default password, and you're not allowed to login with a blank password. a password can be set with

```
sudo apt install guestmount;
```

and

```
mkdir ./mnt;
sudo guestmount -a jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk-kvm.img -i --rw ./mnt;
sudo chroot ./mnt /bin/passwd root
sudo umount mnt
```

to set a root password, or alternatively `sudo chroot ./mnt /bin/passwd --delete root` to allow password-less root login.